# My citation doesn't include the dot in et al for the bibliography

Tags: natbib

I am using the technojournal document class for writing my paper in LaTeX. The latex template that the journal offers use spbasic for the bibliography. This is the first time that it is happening to me whenever I cite something which has multiple authors, et al appears without the dot. Actually I don't know how to solve this issue. If more informations are required please ask me to provide it.

This is a short example of my tex file

```
\documentclass{technojournal}

\journalname{Computers \& Concrete}
\journalvol{11}
\journalnumber{1}
\journalyear{2017}

\doi{2017.1111}

\technocopyright{http://www.techno-press.org/?journal=sem&subpage=8}{1225-4568}{1598-6217}

\title[header title]{The title}

\keywords{keywords} 


\journalname{Computers \& Concrete}
\title[The title]{The title}

\journalname{Computers \& Concrete}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
This is the abstract. The citation is \citet{Mayo-1999}
\end{abstract}

\bibliographystyle{spbasic}      
\bibliography{biblography}   

\end{document}
```

And this is how I built the bibliography:

```
@inproceedings{Mayo-1999,
  title={Strengthening of bridge {G}270 with externally-bonded {CFRP} reinforcement},
  author={Mayo, R and Nanni, A and Gold, W and Barker, M},
  booktitle={SP-188, American Concrete Institute, Proc., 4th International Symposium on FRP for Reinforcement of Concrete Structures (FRPRCS4), Baltimore, MD, Nov},
  pages={429--440},
  year={1999}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`spbasic.bst` defines the `bbl.etal` function to print

```
et~al
```

without a full stop.  Note that `technojournal.cls` (from http://techon-press.org) comes with `technopress.bst` which does print a full stop (and italises the et al):

[image: First sample]

```
\documentclass{technojournal}

\journalname{Computers \& Concrete}
\journalvol{11}
\journalnumber{1}
\journalyear{2017}

\doi{2017.1111}

\technocopyright{http://www.techno-press.org/?journal=sem&subpage=8}{1225-4568}{1598-6217}

\title[header title]{The title}

\keywords{keywords}


\journalname{Computers \& Concrete}
\title[The title]{The title}

\journalname{Computers \& Concrete}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
This is the abstract. The citation is \citet{Mayo-1999}
\end{abstract}

\bibliographystyle{technopress}
\bibliography{bibliography}

\end{document}
```

If you want to use `spbasic` instead, then you will have to make your own copy of `spbasic.bst` and modify the function `bbl.etal` to

```
FUNCTION {bbl.etal}
{ "et~al." }
```

If your are submitting to a journal and they require you to use `spbasic.bst` you should not modify the file and just accept that it is the journal's style.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable answer. Actually, you are right. But the journal uses spbasic style and it doesn't provide et al. for the citations. However, when I refer to the previously published papers, et al. is always with a dot.

Comment: Glad this helped.  It could well be that in actual production the journal uses some other internal tool not available to authors.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can declare author in bibliography as below:

```
@inproceedings{Mayo-1999,
  title={Strengthening of bridge {G}270 with externally-bonded {CFRP} reinforcement},
  author={Mayo, R and others},
  ...
  year= 1999
}
```

This will automatically create `Primary author et al.`.